# Is it considered bad practice to put an infinite loop inside of TThread.Execute?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

i wrote a Thread.descendent class and in the execute method  i put a a infinite loop to listen a com event, is considered a bad Threading practice use a infinite loop to do this ? the applications works fine , does not freeze  and is allways responsive, i just answer because i want use the best method to threading.

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
    while True and not Terminated do
    begin
     AResult:= FListener.GetResult(Param1,Param2,5000);
      if not VarIsNull(AResult) then
        Synchronize(Process);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: If there's an event that terminates the loop, it's not really Infinite now is it?

Comment: Does FListener.GetResult wait if there is no event?

Comment: To stop the thread i use `TMyThread.Terminate`, check the line `while True and not Terminated do` where i check if the thread is Terminated.
`

Comment: David, i updated the code, the listener method has  a timeout parameter in  millisecs to wait.

Comment: That's still looks like the thread will be spinning which isn't ideal. But that's not your question!

Comment: `true and A` is the same thing as `A` for any `A`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is ok to do that. You're checking for `Terminated`, which is good. If your listener allows it and your CPU usage is too high, you can slow down your thread by putting a Sleep(1) in there, but I think it won't be necessary.

Comment: While it's technically OK, it's totally unnecessary and makes the code harder to read. As @David Heffernan pointed out, `True and not Terminated` equates to 'not Terminated', and the second is much easier to read. (Not downvoting, though, because it *is* technically OK even though it's redundant and useless.)

Comment: Yes. The 'true' could be removed. My answer was more about the general  usage of a while loop in a thread, which is what this question is actually about.

Comment: And I see the listener has a timeout itself. That renders my suggestion to put an extra Sleep in the thread unnecessary.

Answer (score 14):

The compiler transforms this into:

```
while not Terminated do
```

When written out this way I'm sure you'll agree it looks perfectly natural. This is a very common idiom.